# WPF ListBox scrollbar is not working

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollbar

```
<ListBox Name="myListBx" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Margin="5,5"
    SelectedValuePath="ColId"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ColId}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            // blabla
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My ListBox contains so many elements and actually the scrollbar should work but it's not even visible.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the parent container (Grid, Stackpanel,...) of your ListBox?

Comment: @Jehof It's a StackPanel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put the ListBox in a Grid. The StackPanel has an
infinite height, so that the ScrollBar does not get enabled or visible.

```
<Grid>
  <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```